# Superimposing static bokeh graphs

Tags: python, python-3.x, bokeh

I'm trying to superimpose bokeh graphs.

This one on top:
http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/image_rgba.html

and this one underneath:
http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/stocks.html

or vice versa.

I'm changing the x-axis to be datetime to fit the stock plot.  But so far this draws a blank chart.  Any suggestions?

```
import numpy as np
import arrow
import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.data as web
#from pandas_data_reader import data as web
from pandas import DataFrame, Series

from bokeh.io import output_notebook
output_notebook()
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file, gridplot

p1 = figure(x_axis_type = "datetime", responsive=True)


N = 100
M = 100
img = np.empty((N,M), dtype=np.uint32)
view = img.view(dtype=np.uint8).reshape((N, M, 4))
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(M):
            view[i, j, 0] = 0  #red
            view[i, j, 1] = int(i/N*160)  #green
            view[i, j, 2] = int(j/N*255)  #blue
            view[i, j, 3] = int(i/N*255)  #alpha

p1 = figure(x_range=['10/1/2015','11/1/2015'], y_range=[0,200]) #changes the view window

all_data = {} 
for ticker in ['AAPL', 'IBM', 'MSFT', 'GOOG']:
    all_data[ticker] = web.get_data_google(ticker, '10/1/2015', '11/1/2015')
AAPL = Series(all_data['AAPL']['Close'])
GOOG = Series(all_data['GOOG']['Close'])
MSFT = Series(all_data['MSFT']['Close'])
IBM = Series(all_data['IBM']['Close'])
p1.line(AAPL.index, AAPL, color='#A6CEE3', legend='Apple')
p1.line(IBM.index, IBM, color='#0022CC', legend='IBM')
p1.line(MSFT.index, MSFT, color='#3322DD', legend='MICROSOFT')

p1.title = "Superimposed info"

p1.image_rgba(image=[img], x=['10/1/2015'], y=[10], dw=['10/15/2015'], dh=[10]) 
p = gridplot([[p1]], toolbar_location=None, min_border=0, h_symmetry=True)
show(p)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

is that what you mean by superimposed ?
[image]

if that the case here is the snippet I used with most of the code you provided, I just changed the call to get the data as I'm behind a proxy and can't get it ;) :

```
from __future__ import division
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import Series
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file

N = 100
img = np.empty((N,N), dtype=np.uint32)
view = img.view(dtype=np.uint8).reshape((N, N, 4))
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        view[i, j, 0] = int(i/N*255)
        view[i, j, 1] = 158
        view[i, j, 2] = int(j/N*255)
        view[i, j, 3] = 255

output_file("image_rgba.html", title="image_rgba.py example")

print img.shape
p = figure(x_range=[0,20], y_range=[0,160])
p.image_rgba(image=[img], x=[0], y=[0], dw=[20], dh=[160])


all_data = {}
for ticker in ['AAPL', 'IBM', 'MSFT', 'GOOG']:
    # all_data[ticker] = web.get_data_google(ticker, '10/1/2015', '11/1/2015')
    path = 'C:/Users/myuser/Downloads/' + ticker.lower() + '.csv'
    all_data[ticker] = pd.read_csv(path)

AAPL = Series(all_data['AAPL']['Close'])
GOOG = Series(all_data['GOOG']['Close'])
MSFT = Series(all_data['MSFT']['Close'])
IBM = Series(all_data['IBM']['Close'])

p.line(AAPL.index, AAPL, color='#A6CEE3', legend='Apple')
p.line(IBM.index, IBM, color='#0022CC', legend='IBM')
p.line(MSFT.index, MSFT, color='#3322DD', legend='MICROSOFT')

show(p)  # open a browser
```

edit : `p = figure(x_range=[0, 20], y_range=[0, 160], x_axis_type="datetime")` will change the x_axis to a datetime object, but your data index are integers so the 1 to 20 will be displayed as number of seconds since epoch and see this [issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/813) : I think you won't be able to display the axe as dd/mm/yyyy or whatever the format you want at the moment.

Comment: Yes that is what I mean by superimposed.  I still can't recreate what you have done here but this is closer as I'm able to get the Image_rgba with a legend.  I changed to Py27 to match.  I'm supposing in your data that your date index is converted to epoch timestamps. (0-20 seconds).  I found stocks that were sold in the 1970's to match. ('DIS' and 'DD' from web.get_data_yahoo()).  I'll keep working on it.

Comment: csv data come from http://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=GOOG&startdate=Oct+01%2C+2015&enddate=Nov+01%2C+2015&output=csv sorry I couldn't use yours so I digged into panda code to see what url they were reaching :)